# Spring MVC : how do I show data from DAO classes

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a DAO java class that has a method called `getTableFromDatabase()`, it queries the MySQL and return `resultTable`, a hashmap of data. I want to use this hashmap and print the content in my jsp page using Spring MVC, how should I do this?

I know that I can use JSTL to print a table, my problem is how to pass this table from DAO to jsp page.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In spring mvc you have to return a `ModelAndView` class and this class will carry corresponding jsp file and parameters will be passed to jsp.

For example

In your controller request handler method you will return an instance of ModelAndView

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView handle(){
  ModelAndView ret = new ModelAndView("view name");
  ret.addAttribute("x","value");

}
```

in your jsp you can access to x via ${x} syntax.

Spring mvc document reference:

> public ModelAndView addObject(Object attributeValue) Add an attribute
>   to the model using parameter name generation. Parameters:
>   attributeValue - the object to add to the model (never null) See Also:
>   ModelMap.addAttribute(Object), getModelMap()

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html

Comment: You don't have to return a ModelAndView object .. you can just return a string representing a reference to a view and handle the Model separately.

Comment: it is another way, both works in your case you have to inject ModelMap to your controller method.

Comment: you can also inject just the Model interface into your handler method